# How can I reference item (i) in Theorem 1.1 such that it displays "Theorem 1.1-(i)"?

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, theorems, enumitem, autoref

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools, thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref, cleveref}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin = section]{theorem}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{foo}
    \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
        \item\label{bar}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

I want to obtain a reference to the item labeled "bar" in the theorem labeled "foo". The reference should display as "Theorem 1.1-i". How can I do this? If I use `\autoref{foo}` I only obtain "Theorem 1.1" and if I use `\autoref{bar}` I obtain "item (i)".

Comment: `\autoref{foo}-\ref{bar}`

Comment: @ferahfeza I've tried that before but this produces some space between "Theorem 1.1-" and "(i)".

Comment: Look at may answer. There is no spaces, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? Use `\autoref{foo}-\ref{bar}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools, thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref, cleveref}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

%\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{foo}
Lorem ipsum...
    \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
        \item\label{bar1}
        \item\label{bar2}
        \item\label{bar3}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}
In \autoref{foo}-\ref{bar1} and in \autoref{foo}-\ref{bar2} and in \autoref{foo}-\ref{bar3} \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using the `enumitem` package, you might as well use its `\newlist`/`\setlist` machinery to create a bespoke enumerate-like environment, called `thmenum}` in the code below, and use in theorem environments.

[image]

If you would like to change the prefix from "theorem item" to just "theorem", just replace `\crefname{thmenumi}{theorem item}{theorem items}` with `\crefname{thmenumi}{theorem}{theorems}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, mathtools, thmtools}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin = section]{theorem}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\newlist{thmenum}{enumerate}{1} % to be used only inside 'theorem' environments
\setlist[thmenum]{label=\textup{(\roman*)},
                  ref=\thetheorem-\textup{(\roman*)}}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{thmenumi}{theorem item}{theorem items}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}  % just for this example
\begin{theorem}\label{foo}
    \begin{thmenum} Consider \dots
        \item\label{bar} Bla bla bla
        \item\label{bor} Blo blo blo
    \end{thmenum}
\end{theorem}

\cref{bar}

\cref{bor,bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Addendum - I honestly don't think the OP's desired formatting is all that good. When cross-referencing enumerated items in a theorem (or proposition, or whatever), one should just refer to them as "items (i) and (ii) in Theorem 1" and *not* "Theorems 1-(i) and 1-(ii)". However, that's clearly the OP's choice to make, not mine.

Comment: If I want to use "item (i) and (ii) of Theorem 1.1" at some other point, can we still achieve this?

Comment: @0xbadf00d - Yes. Just delete the string `ref=\thetheorem-\textup{(\roman*)}` from the `\setlist` instruction, and change `\crefname{thmenumi}{theorem item}{theorem items}` to `\crefname{thmenumi}{item}{items}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ref` key, defined by `znumitem.

Unrelated: needless to load `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`: the latter does it for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, mathtools, thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref, cleveref}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\declaretheorem[numberwithin = section]{theorem}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{1}
\begin{theorem}\label{foo}
\begin{enumerate}[(i),ref =\cref{foo}-\roman*]
\item\label{bar} Really?
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

We see in \ref{bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]